# How to make a function happen in a for loop without repeating a command after each loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Right now I am working on a file where it lets you customise a password. Each section lets you choose between a name, number, and more with a certain amount of sections. I can't figure out how to place the code that generates each section in the num_of_pass for loop without repeating the text
'What would you like in section #' + str(current_section) + '? (name, number, letter, symbol, year, day, month) '
each time it gives a new password. How could I make this work?

```
    names = ['Tim', 'Alex', 'Thomas', 'Katrina', 'Joshua', 'James', 'John', 'Emily', 'Mary', 'Patricia', 'Jennifer',
             'Linda', 'Elizabeth', 'Robert', 'Michael', 'William', 'David', 'Richard', 'Ashley', 'Damon', 'Max']

    options = ['name', 'number', 'letter', 'symbol', 'year', 'day', 'month']

    days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

    months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

sections = input('How many sections would you like? ')
        num_of_pass = input('How many passwords would you like? ')
        current_section = 1
        for num in range(int(sections)):
            section_type = input('What would you like in section #' + str(current_section) + '? (name, number, letter, symbol, year, day, month) ')
            if section_type == 'name':
                section = random.choice(names)
            elif section_type == 'number':
                section = str(random.randint(1, 9))
            elif section_type == 'letter':
                section = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
            elif section_type == 'symbol':
                section = str(random.choice(string.punctuation))
            elif section_type == 'year':
                section = str(random.randint(1000, 2020))
            elif section_type == 'day':
                section = random.choice(days)
            elif section_type == 'month':
                section = random.choice(months)
            password = password + section
            current_section += 1
        print(password)
        password = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply put the `input` statement outside of the loop, or there's a work around it - put it in a condition:

```
for num in range(int(sections)):
            if count == 0:
                section_type = input('What would you like in section #' + str(current_section) + '? (name, number, letter, symbol, year, day, month) ')
                count += 1
            if section_type == 'name':
                section = random.choice(names)
```

Comment: For the work around, what do I set count to before running the command? Where would I put it?

Comment: Declare the count variable as `count = 0` outside the loop.

Comment: It doesn't work. It only gives me out 1 password, even though I have asked for two, and it also only lets me choose what is in the first section and then repeats it for all the sections,

Comment: Is there somewhere I can contact you personally? Some place we could collaborate, I could help you out there... Do you have a Discord account?

Comment: I don't have a discord account, but I do have skype and the xbox app.